# Laravel cache:clear broke application

Tags: php, laravel

After executing

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

The application doesn't work anymore, it seems to be something about the `session`. Stopped create the session files.

The error returning is:

```php
file_put_contents(path/to/file/storage/framework/sessions/PullrofroFB2gGJNA8v7Zo7OcdTzno4ZDTVmfBBi): 
failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory
```

Comment: why did you run `cache:clear` in the first place? just wondering .. but have you cleared your cookies since you did this?

Comment: Looks like your session config is wrong. Look in config/sessions.php : Session File location ('files'). default value is 'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

Comment: @lagbox Yes I did. I run `cache:clear` trying to refresh the `.env` file.

Comment: @GertB. The `sessions.php` file seems to be fine.

Comment: `cache:clear` is clearing your actual cache store, it has nothing to do with the route/view/config caching ... just fyi for future reference

Comment: @ThRnk the error is literally what you posted? in that case the session storage is set to path/to/file. It could be in your .env file too. Or where you set the session.

Comment: What have you tried to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `config:cache` and the `cache:clear` don't refer to the same cache.

If you run `php artisan config:cache --help` shows the following description:

> Description:   Create a cache file for faster configuration loading

Running `php artisan cache:clear --help` shows the following description:

> Description:  Flush the application cache

And there's also another command: `config:clear` which

> Description: Remove the configuration cache file

So... `cache:clear` only clears the application cache while `config:clear` will remove the cache file created by `config:cache`. Also you may try running `config:cache` whith admin privileges.

Comment: Running `config:cache` again solve the problem, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Glad to help you